# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method' while trying to multiply a few variables using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror, python-3.8

I am trying o plot a simple linear regression using numpy and seaborn. However, I cannot make the multiplication work for my `y` variable. The error I get is the following:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

I have tried to pass parameters in an `int()` function but still not able to solve the problem.

The code is as follows:

```
import numPy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


np.random.seed(123)
N = 20
beta0 = -4
beta1 = 2
x = np.random.randn(N)
e = np.random.randn(N)
y = beta0 + beta1 * x + e
true_x = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100)
true_y = beta0 + beta1*true_x


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(x, y, s = 40, label = 'Data')
sns.lineplot(true_x, true_y, color = 'red', label = 'True Model')
ax.set_xlabel('x', fontsize = 14)
ax.set_title(fr"$y = {beta0} + ${beta1}$x + \epsilon$", fontsize = 16)
ax.set_ylabel('y', fontsize=14, rotation=0, labelpad=10)
ax.legend(loc = 4)
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Change `np.random.randn` to `np.random.randn()`.  You're not currently calling it, you're just assigning it to `x` and `e`, which clearly won't work.

Comment: Traceback please.  Or at least show the problem line!   The error says that the 2nd argument is a function, not an evaluated array.

Comment: @TomKarzes thank you very much. I updated the code and put `N` inside the `()` and added `plt.show()`. Everything is working fine. Please add your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the correct answer.